# How to prove alternative form of Fisher information

Tags: statistics, fisher-information

Assuming the FI regularity conditions hold. The Fisher information matrix $I(\theta;X)$ about $\theta$ based on $X$ is defined as the matrix with elements
$$
I_{i,j}(\theta;X)=Cov_{\theta}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{i}}\log f_{X}(X|\theta),\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}\log f_{X}(X|\theta)\Big)
$$
However, an alternative form is given in my studybook
$$
I_{i,j}=-E_{\theta}(\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\theta_{i}\partial\theta_{j}}\log f_{X}(x|\theta))
$$
I am not able to proof the alternative form, since I am not able to find why the following equality holds
$$
-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\theta_{i}\partial\theta_{j}}\log f_{X}(x|\theta)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{i}}\log f_{X}(x|\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}\log f_{X}(x|\theta)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that:

### $-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\theta_{i}\partial\theta_{j}}\log f_{X}(x|\theta)=-\frac{\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\theta_{i}\partial\theta_{j}}f_{X}(x|\theta)}{f_{X}(x|\theta)}+\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{i}}f_{X}(x|\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}} f_{X}(x|\theta)}{f^{2}_{X}(x|\theta)}$

Now taking the expectation left and right of this relation, we find that:

### $-\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\theta_{i}\partial\theta_{j}}\log f_{X}(x|\theta)]=\mathbb{E}[(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{i}}\log f_{X}(x|\theta)(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}\log f_{X}(x|\theta))]$

This is because of the fact that:

### $-\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{i}} \log f_X(x;\theta)]=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{i}}\int f_X(x|\theta)\text{dx}$

So the alternative form follows.